# cannot convert to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

if i execute the following code i get a cannot convert to object error;
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'validation.messages.field' to object

```
$.fn.validate = function(validation) {
    $.each(validation.rules, function(field, fieldRules){
        $.each(fieldRules, function(rule, ruleValue){
            var fieldValue = $('[name=' + field + ']').val();
            if (eval(rule + '(fieldValue, ruleValue)') == false){
                alert(validation.rules.field.rule);
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            };
        });
    });
}
```

the problem is the

`alert(validation.messages.field.rule);`

'field' = 'persoon_voornaam' and 'rule' = 'required'
and `validation.messages.persoon_voornaam.required` works just fine.

What am i doing wrong?

validation is a JSON that look like this:

```
{
    rules: {
        persoon_voornaam: {
            required: true, 
            minlength: 5,
        },
        postcode_bestemming: {
            required: true, 
            minlength: 7,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        persoon_voornaam: {
            required: 'Dit veld is verplicht',
            minlengt: 'Dit veld moet minstens 5 lang zijn', 
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: That is invalid JSON. Misplaced `,` and not using `"` for example.

Comment: What you show is not JSON it is an object literal. It is most likely a problem with the trailing `,`.

Comment: `evvvaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalllllllll` noooooo noooooooo don't hurt me, please!

Comment: Did you try to remove coma after each last element in the object?

Comment: @jAndy, if you trust the data source `eval` is not bad or should hurt your eyes.

Comment: @Anders: But in this case it might be better to have a name->function mapping then using `eval`. Afaik `eval` evaluates the the string in global scope...

Comment: removed all the trailing , but doest help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be:

```
alert(validation.rules[field][rule])
```

To clarify:

`validation.rules` is an object while `field` is a variable with the string `'persoon_voornaam'`.

`validation.rules.persoon_voornaam` is an object and the same as `validation.rules['persoon_voornaam']`.

Comment: +1 Or you could just use the value parameter `alert(ruleValue)`.

Comment: dazz: validation.rules is an object while field is a variable with the string 'persoon_voornaam'. validation.rules.persoon_voornaam is an object and the same as validation.rules['persoon_voornaam'] - hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem was already given. I want to propose an improved version of your code, to make your code more reusable (otherwise there is not need to attach it to the jQuery object).

1. Your are not making use of the fact that this function will be applied to elements selected by your selector. You are selecting *all* form elements that match a certain name.
2. `eval` is evil. You would have to pollute the global namespace with functions named `required` and `minlength`.

The following code tries to adress these issues:

```
$.fn.validate = (function() {
    var validators = {
        'required': function(value, ruleValue) {
             /*...*/
         },
         'minlength': function(value, ruleValue) {
            /*...*/
         }
    };

    return function(validation, config) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var errors = [];
            var $element = $(this);
            $.each(validation.rules, function(field, fieldRules){
                $.each(fieldRules, function(rule, ruleValue){
                    var fieldValue = $element.find('[name=' + field + ']').val();
                    if (rule in validators && validators[rule].call(null, fieldValue, ruleValue) === false){
                        var message = (field in validation.messages && rule in validation.messages[field]) ? validation.messages[field][rule] : '';
                        errors.push([field, rule, message])
                        return false;
                    }
                });
           });

           // the following part could be written shorter as 
           //  var cb = erros.length > 0 ? 'onerror' : 'onsuccess';
           //  if(typeof config[cb] === 'function') {
           //      config[cb](errors);
           //  }
           // but it will pass an empty array to success (which is not a problem
           // I just though it might be confusing)

           if(erros.length > 0) {
               if(typeof config.onerror === 'function') {
                   config.onerror(errors);
               }
           }
           else {
               if(typeof config.onsuccess === 'function') {
                   config.onsuccess();
               }
           }
       });
   }
}());
```

Then you can call the function with:

```
$('#yourFormId').validate(valditation, {
    onerror: function(errors) {
         // do something with errors
    },
    onsuccess: function() {
         // do something else
    }
});
```

and it will only validate the fields in the form.

Comment: it checks only the fields inside a certain div, this is a stripped down version of the code. But ill have a look at the eval() alternative. Just used it because i couldn't find a better alternative

Comment: @Dazz: Ah ok then :D Anyway, maybe my code gives you some ideas... (it's untested though)

Comment: it seems to be working except for the  var fieldValue = $(this).find('[name=' + field + ']').val(); where $(this) isn't the object where the validate is called on. If i use $('#thedivname') it works

Comment: @Dazz: Ah right. `this` refers to the rule your are looping. I updated my code. You just have to capture the value of `$(this)` before the nested `$.each` loops.

Comment: one more question. What does this line do? "$.extend(config, {onerror: function(){}, onsucces: function(){}});" I know what $.extend does but the code seems to working fine without that line.

Comment: @Dazz: It is just making sure that if you call the function with e.g. `$('#yourFormId').validate(validation)` (i.e. without a config object or one that misses one of the key), calling e.g. `config.onerror(errors)` later won't fail. But to be fair, it would be better to do add `if(typeof config.onerror === 'function')` before you call the function, in case when `onerror` is set, but is not a function. This is just for robustness, otherwise the function would through an error. I updated my code accordingly.